# QGIS install mac 10.7.5

Tags: qgis, mac

Have iMac with OS 10.7.5. This is the first time I am installing QGIS. Everything was downloaded from kyngchaos.

This is what I did in that order:
Downloaded QGIS-2.12.0-1. Tried to install.
It asked for GDAL 1.11. Got GDAL_complete 1.11(EB). Installed.
Next QGIS asked for matplotlib. Got matplotlib-1.4.3. Installed.
Next QGIS asked for PROJ_framework 4.9. Got PROJ_Framework-4.9.2-2. Installed.
Next QGIS asked for SQLite3_Framework. Downloaded SQLite3_Framework-3.8.7.3-1. Installed.
At this point QGIS installed.

When I click on Q in applications, it says 'QGIS quit unexpectedly'. 
ERROR:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Clearly something is not as it should be. 
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [KyngChaos archive](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive#qgis)

[image]

Yon can see that GDAL 1.11.1, PROJ 4.9, GEOS 3.4.2, SQLite3 3.7.17, UnixImageIO 1.5.0 are included in the GDAL complete Framework, therefore you don't need to download the individual Frameworks

The order to install QGIS is:

1. install the GDAL Complete 1.11EB Framework

[image]

Content of the GDAL complete framework (with [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/))

[image]

The frameworks are installed in (control with [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/get.html))

[image]

2. Install the [KyngChaos matplotlib and Numpy Python module](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python)

The Python modules are installed in

[image]

3. Launch QGIS

Now, if you want to upgrade the individual Frameworks, you can download and install them individually

The best solution for you is to delete all the installed Frameworks and reinstall all following the procedure.

Comment: I ran this precise package from the Kyngchaos site - GDAL_complete1.11EB. I also installed Numpy from this package. QGIS still asked for all the others in that order. They were all installed in the Frameworks and Python folders you have indicated, properly. QGIS still does not launch. I am not upgrading anything at all, just installing the basic software for the first time.

Comment: In fact, QGIS asks for SQLite_Framework 3.8 or later specifically. I downloaded 8.7.3-1 and installed. The 3.7.17 is not working.

Comment: QGIS also asks for PROJ framework 4.9, again specifically. So I installed 4.9.2-2.

Comment: There is a mismatch between what QGIS 2.12.0-1 requires and what is listed in GDAL complete 1.11EB. Sorry, I mistyped earlier. Installed SQLite 3.8.7.3-1.

Comment: GDAL complete 1.11EB is most definitely not installing the PROJ and SQLite frameworks on its own.

Comment: The PROJ and SQLite frameworks are in the GDAL complete Framework (checked with Pacifist or Suspicious Package) and all works in my case with 10.7.5

Comment: I removed all traces of QGIS 2.12.0-1 and reinstalled. It does exactly the same process as before. It does not install the frameworks and asks for them. And still does not launch. I have no idea what to do any more.

Comment: I did this again today. Removed all QGIS related stuff. Started from the beginning. You are right. The GDAL complete 1.11EB installs all the frameworks, PROJ and SQLite, in proper folders. I also installed Numpy from the same package and then matplotlib, in that order. Yet, when I started installation of QGIS 2.12.0-1 itself, it said failure, and asked me to install SQLite framework version 3.8. I have stopped at this point. Perhaps I should use an earlier version of QGIS with GDAL 1.11EB?

Comment: I tried to use QGIS 2.10.1-1 with GDAL1.11EB. GDAL installed all the frameworks. But QGIS still gives the same message: install SQLite Framework 3.8.3. When I try to do that it asks for PROJ framework 4.9. There is some severe mismatch here. Can somebody help to resolve this?